# Intel S5520UR and Raid activation key

Tags: raid, intel

If I add Raid Activation Key:

```
AXXRAKSAS2
```

and  Memory:

```
AXXMINIDIMM512
```

To the S5520UR Intel motherboard, it enables:

> "enables full intelligent SAS HW RAID for the Intel Servers with a
>   LSI1078-based active midplane."

Does this mean I'll get some performance advantage, or that it just unlocks the new RAID 5,50,60 ..etc.

**NOTE:** It uses SATA HDDs, not SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AXXRAKSAS2 Install Guide](http://pdfs.icecat.biz/pdf/21765277-4195.pdf)

According to the guide:

> This guide is specific to the Intel
>   ®
>   RAID Activation Key with the order code, AXXRAKSAS2.
>   This key enables hardware RAID across all mod
>   es (0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 50, and 60) on these Intel
>   ®
>   server
>   boards and systems that include an Intel
>   ®
>   Integrated Server RAID Module using the LSI* 1078
>   ROC controller:

So, like most, it is designed as a "license key" to unlock the additional RAID levels.  The performance is still limited to the actual LSI card's abilities.